# Difficulties of klampt installation with pip

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am currently trying to install Klampt (http://motion.pratt.duke.edu/klampt/#install) on MacOSX. I have tried to install it with pip, brew, and from source but it hasn't worked. I asked my friend who has windows to try and install it using pip and it does not work for them either.

This is the error I get when I try to install it with pip:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement klampt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for klampt

Both pip and python are up to date. I also tried downloading it with pip3 and it did not work either.

Does anyone know what I could try next?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Klampt, 0.8.2, [provides](https://pypi.org/project/Klampt/0.8.2/#files) wheels only up to Python 3.7 but not for 3.8. So to install it from wheels you need to downgrade to Python 3.7 or [ask](https://github.com/krishauser/Klampt/issues) the authors if they gonna provide wheels for Python 3.8.